# Need C# RegEx to find a a word and a number.

Tags: regex

I have a need to find a word and a number in a sentence like this:

> The state Mchine is at stage 4. next stage is queued.

I need to find only state and number 4. and ignore the rest.

I have this:

```
@"\b(state)(?:\W+\w+){1,10}?\W+(\d)*\b"
```

but it is also including all the words in between the matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us your code. I can probably guess you're getting the first element of the matches array, which includes the entire match, not the matches matched inside parentheses.

Comment: Here's the Snip from thre code that tries tp detect the state of the queue and need to look for the phrase "state" and some times "status" and will need to retrieve the status code. string line1; string errcode = @"\b(status|error|state)\b(?:\W+\w+){1,10}?\W+\b(\d)*\b"; Regex defaultRegex = new Regex(errcode, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); MatchCollection myMatchCollection = Regex.Matches(line1, errcode); richTextBox1.AppendText(myMatchCollection.Count.ToString()); foreach (Match myMatch in myMatchCollection) { richTextBox1.AppendText(myMatch.ToString());

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to capture from the text. You need the number, and what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var input = "The state Mchine is at stage 4. next stage is queued.";
            var pattern = @"[^\s]+.(?<state>\w+)[\w\s]+(?<stage>\d+)\.";
            var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["state"].Value); //state
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["stage"].Value); //4
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great, But When I read this Line It came back blank and nothing matched? "your prcess was stuck at while processing state 490." 
 
 
I changed the pattern to @"[^\s]+.\b(?<state>\w+)\b[\w\s]+(?<stage>(\d)*)\."
 
 
But that still did not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Here's the Snip from thre code that tries tp detect the state of the queue and need to look for the phrase "state" and some times "status" and will need to retrieve the status code.
  
  
  
string line1;
string errcode = @"\b(status|error|state)\b(?:\W+\w+){1,10}?\W+\b(\d)*\b";


Regex defaultRegex = new Regex(errcode, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);


MatchCollection myMatchCollection = Regex.Matches(line1, errcode);
richTextBox1.AppendText(myMatchCollection.Count.ToString());
foreach (Match myMatch in myMatchCollection)
{

    richTextBox1.AppendText(myMatch.ToString());

}

Comment: @SamRam if the question is not resolved, don't click the green check under an answer. Wait till your question is answered, then you can click the check mark on the appropriate answer.